# Taking from index array multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

here is my situation. Suppose you have an array A of some elements, A is np.ndarray, and B - also np.ndarray, where B[i] is how many times I'd like to take element A[i] for the output. Example: A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), B = np.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 3]). The result should be np.array([3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]).

So how to make it in numpy fast, without for-loops etc.

Thanks.

Tried to find something appropriate in numpy doc, but no success.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html): `np.repeat(A, B)`

Comment: what if B is matrix, and I want to make it along rows of B? np repeat won't work this time

Comment: @ДенисСтафилов Can you give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm not sure about an output you expect. It might be array with multiple sizes of rows which is not supported in `numpy`